# Data type mismatch in criteria expression error when trying to insert into Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to insert values entered by a user on a Winform into the following Access table:
[image]

The C# code is:

```
    OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Projects (projectTitle,partyID,receiveDate,dueDate, projectTypeID, pages, "+
        "lines, words, prepay, cost, settled,projectComment)"
    + " VALUES (@projectTitle,@partyID,@receiveDate,@dueDate,@projectTypeID,@pages, @lines, @words, @prepay, @cost, @settled, @projectComment)", conn);


    PersianCalendar p=new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime thisDate=DateTime.Now;
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@projectTitle", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProjectTitle.Text;
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@partyID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboProjectType.SelectedValue.ToString());
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiveDate", string.Format( "{0}, {1}/{2}/{3} {4}:{5}:{6}",
        p.GetDayOfWeek(thisDate), p.GetYear(thisDate),p.GetMonth(thisDate),p.GetDayOfMonth(thisDate), p.GetHour(thisDate),p.GetMinute(thisDate),p.GetSecond(thisDate))) ;                        
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@dueDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comboDay.Text + "/" + comboMonth.Text + "/" + comboYear.Text;          
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@projectTypeID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboContractParty.SelectedValue.ToString());
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pages", Convert.ToInt32(txtPages.Text));
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lines", Convert.ToInt32(txtLines.Text));
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@words", Convert.ToInt32(txtWords.Text));
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", Convert.ToDouble(txtWholeProjCost.Text));
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prepay", Convert.ToDouble(txtPrePay.Text));
    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@settled", chkSettled.CheckState); 
    oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@projectComment", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtComment.Text.ToString();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }
```

The exception says:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

I rechecked the types, but don't know where the error is raised from.

Comment: Does your code work if you temporarily replace the current (string) value of the @receiveDate parameter with just `thisDate`?

Comment: @GordThompson, it shows this error after using just thisDate: 
**- ************ Exception Text **************
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)**

Comment: @GordThompson the above error was due to null input that seems to be solved by setting default 0 value for the entries. However, I'm still getting the error "Data type mismatch".

Comment: What happens if you use `... VALUES (@projectTitle,@partyID,Date(),@dueDate, ...` and comment out the statement that creates the @receiveDate parameter?

Comment: what is that? I haven't seen like that before. What is Date() in the parentheses?

Comment: `Date()` is an Access SQL function that returns the current date.

Comment: Cool, but is it ok to use it in the query this way?

Comment: Yes, it is quite okay to use the `Date()` function as a value in an Access SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`receiveDate` and `dueDate` are defined as `DateTime` in the Database but you are passing text (string) to the parameter:

```
oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiveDate", string.Format(... 

oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@dueDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ...
```

Pass actual `DateTime` vars and it should work.  Since the date(s) are in pieces, I would create them first so they can be tested:

```
// why not use thisDate rather than chopping it up to recombine?
DateTime recDate = New DateTime(p.Getyear(thisDate)...);

// personally, I might use a DateTimePicker rather than 3 CBOs
DateTime dueDate  = New DateTime(ConvertToInt32(comboYear.Text), ...
```

Then pass them as params.  If you use `Add` specify `OleDbType.Date`:

```
oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiveDate", recDate); 
...
oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dueDate", dueDate);
```

Comment: I chop date because i am actually converting gregorian to Persian date. I have already passed varchar oledbtype to access datetime cells and it worked.

Comment: Ok, the calendar conversion makes sense.  Allowing Access to convert string to date can work but rather than getting a Date type you can  check before inserting, this is the kind of error you get.  The other fields all do appear to match that it is still likely to be something with the Date and/or calendar conversion.